# project Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin

Hello Team getting following error on mvn clean install.

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.0:compile (default-compile) on project Fatal error compiling: error: release version 17 not supported -> [Help 1]

I have following config in Pom.xml

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.10.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>17</source>
                        <target>17</target>
                        <release>17</release>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
 <properties> 
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
 </properties>
```

I tried different versions of maven-compiler-plugin and expecting build to run successful

Comment: What is the output of `mvn -v`?

Comment: You are using a JDK which is JDK8 or less... Best recommendation to use only `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` and do not configure source/target/release in the plugin configuration...

Answer (score 0):

It seems old Maven version (e.g. 3.6.x)
Reinstall the new one, e.g. from https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi